Unable to Persist HashSet<T> with jsonb Column Type in EF Core after Upgrading to .NET 9 and PostgreSQL 9.0.1
I'm upgrading a project from .NET 6 to .NET 9 and PostgreSQL to version 9.0.1.
In my domain model, I have the following property:
public HashSet<Guid> Property { get; set; }


In the database, both properties are stored as jsonb columns with the default value set to '[]'::jsonb.
However, after upgrading, I'm encountering the following error:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Guid]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Guid]'.

I suspect the issue is related to how EF Core serializes HashSet<T> and jsonb columns in the upgraded environment.
Additional Details:
Previous EF Core/Database Behavior: This worked seamlessly in .NET 6 and PostgreSQL (older version).
My Questions:
Is there a breaking change in EF Core or PostgreSQL that affects how HashSet<T> is serialized/deserialized for jsonb columns?
How can I correctly persist and query HashSet<T> with jsonb in the upgraded environment?
Is there a workaround or a best practice to avoid this InvalidCastException?
I tried to somehow manage the serialization manually:
builder
    .Property(x => x.Property)
    .HasColumnType("jsonb")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("'[]'::jsonb")
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, new JsonSerializerOptions { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull }),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HashSet<Guid>>(v, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }) ?? new HashSet<Guid>()

);

But it didn't helped.

It won't fix your issue but Postgres 9.0.1 is waaay out of date, current version is 16

excuse me I didn't mentioned I am using this package:
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 9.0.1 is the latest one.

Why are you using HashSet<Guid> in the first place? That's what the error complains about. The data is an array. HashSet<T> doesn't implement IList<T> so it can't be used to store arrays or lists. Use Guid[] if you don't want to add data or List<Guid> if you do

@coder123 Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL is the EF provider version, not the PostgreSQL version.

You don't need HasConversion either, NpgSql already maps JSON columns in various ways. The manual conversion prevents Npgsql from translating LINQ queries to native JSON methods
